# Jquery expand and collapse functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Jquery/javascript and I have myself a bunch of levels of links that I need to organize in to lists that are expandable and collapsible via a +/- button.

An example of the information I am working with is:

```
Category1 (Level 1)
- Subcategory 1 (Level 2)
- Subcategory 2
- Subcategory 3
Category2 (Level 1)
- Subcategory 1 (Level 2)
- Subcategory 2
- Subcategory 3
Category3 (Level 1)
- Subcategory 1 (Level 2)
----Subcategory 1 (Level 3)
- Subcategory 2
- Subcategory 3
```

Code wise, it looks like this:

```
<div class="navCol">
<h4>Pet Club</h4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/pc/home">Pet Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pc/articles">Arts</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pc/coupons">ns</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pc/pet-prescriptions">Pet Prescrions</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="navCol">
<h4>Fresh Ideas</h4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/fi/cooking-guide">Know Yur Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fi/departments">Depaments</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fi/gluten-free">Free</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fi/house-of-bbq">HoBQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fi/how-to-shop">rt</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fi/kids-cooking-club">Kidsb</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fi/price-chopper-products">Tr</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="navCol">
<h4>vings</h4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/vings/advantedge-card">w</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/baby-club">Bb</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/blue-rhino">asdf</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/grocery-apps">On </a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/grocery-coupons">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/grocery-offers">Em</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/grocery-sweepstakes">P</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/meal-deals">W</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/pc">Pet</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/price-chopper-fuel-advantedge">Fuel</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/school-vings-program">School</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vings/weekly-flyer">Weekly</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click the category +- and it will show/hide all the links underneath it. Same with subcategory1 in category3 where I am dealing with the third level. How would I be able to implement all the way down to level 3?

Should I precede all my links with L1, L2, L3 tags? I have looked at some questions that deal with the +/- sign and implementation but I do not understand a lot of it.

Also, how would I go about implementing a button that shows all or expands all on toggle? That is, it would expand to the deepest levels and collapse back to show only the level 1 categories.

If you any place where I can start to learn this on my own, that would be greatly appreciated as well. This is my first project and I am confused as to where to start.

Comment: See jQueryUI's [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).

Comment: @Josh Thank you for the link. I am using visual studio (web). How would go about testing the javascript with the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to start by thinking about your HTML structure.  You'll need some kind of nested elements to express the list.  I would recommend using nested `<ul>` elements because it semantically represents your data structure.

Don't worry about how many levels there are; if you do it right, the same code will work for a collapsible element at any level.

You'll really have three tasks: knowing when the tree element is clicked on, finding its children, and toggling their visibility.

You can use jQuery's [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler to determine when the element is clicked on.  Be careful, though: if you have, for example, nested `<li>` elements, and you use `$('li').click` as your event, you'll catch multiple clicks for sub-elements (as they will also trigger their parent's `click` event).  So you'll have to be a little clever with your selector.

Once you're able to detect the click, then you can find any sub-items by using jQuery's [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function.

Finally, it's a simple matter of toggling the visibility of child elements, which you can do easily with jQuery's [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

Lastly, I agree with the sentiment of Josh's comment: why re-invent the wheel?  If you're doing it to learn, that's great, and you can use the approach I outlined in this answer.  If you just need it done, you should look into using an existing jQuery extension, like Josh's suggestion of [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) or [jQuery Treeview](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Please see the edit, I have posted some code about the structure of my code. Problem is, I don't know how to use an existing jQuery extension. I want something similar to Sample 2 - Navigation in the jQuery Treeview. What do I need to do to set myself up with that navigation? Thanks!

Comment: First download jQuery Treeview (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/), then look at some of the samples.  Look at the code...it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

While I'd usually advise getting to grips fully with javascript before going head on with jQuery, the latter provides a much easier solution here.

Take a look at [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Edit: Josh's suggesting is a fine one, but it might be worth getting to grips with building simpler versions beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example http://jsfiddle.net/xNh6R/4/

Javascript:

```
$('.level1').click(function(){
    if($(this).next('div').is(':visible')){
        $(this).next('div').hide("blind");
    } else {
        $(this).next('div').show("blind");
    }
});

$('.level2').click(function(){
    if($(this).next('div').is(':visible') && $(this).next('div').hasClass("level3")){
        $(this).next('div').hide("blind");
    } else if($(this).next('div').hasClass("level3")) {
        $(this).next('div').show("blind");
    }
});​
```